# React app builds successfully but shows white screen on chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

if someone could help that'd be great. I am following a react tutorial except at some point chrome went blank. When I inspect the page, nothing is in the body html tags. The code compiles and builds successfully though. I'm thinking it's a stupid typo or something, but I am no pro. Please let me know if you find my error!

[Terminal On Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8WR1.png)

[image: App.js]

[image: index.js]

[image: homepage index.js]

Answer (score 0):

you created the router but no routes. in app.js

```
import React from "react"
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom"
import Home from './pages'
function App () {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi all it was a problem in one of my components. The lack of error messages made me think it had something to do with the construction of the app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).